# unable to insert data frame to an existing oracle table

Tags: r, oracle

dput(head(dat,10))

```
structure(list(DATE = c("14-04-2013 00:02:30", "14-04-2013 00:03:00", 
"14-04-2013 00:03:30", "14-04-2013 00:04:00", "14-04-2013 00:04:30", 
"14-04-2013 00:05:00", "14-04-2013 00:05:30", "14-04-2013 00:06:00", 
"14-04-2013 00:06:30", "14-04-2013 00:07:00"), LPAR = c("server1", 
"server1", "server1", "server1", "server1", 
"server1", "server1", "server1", "server1", 
"server1"), ENT = c("0.50", "0.50", "0.50", "0.50", "0.50", 
"0.50", "0.50", "0.50", "0.50", "0.50"), USR_SYS_CPU_PCT = c(73L, 
74L, 75L, 75L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 75L, 74L), ENT_PCT = c(345.6, 
397.7, 394.2, 418.6, 349.2, 358.9, 585.7, 443.8, 464.9, 483.1
), PHYSICAL_CPU_USED = c(1.73, 1.99, 1.97, 2.09, 1.75, 1.79, 
2.93, 2.22, 2.32, 2.42)), .Names = c("DATE", "LPAR", "ENT", "USR_SYS_CPU_PCT", 
"ENT_PCT", "PHYSICAL_CPU_USED"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to insert dat data frame to an existing oracle table called VMSTAT. I am doing to this insert:

```
library(RODBC)
ch=odbcConnect("<dsn name>",pwd = "<password>")
sqlSave(ch,dat, tablename="VMSTAT",append=T)
odbcClose(ch)
```

not working. My R session is crashing. The VMSTAT table has the same column names as the data frame. Has anybody try to insert data frames to Oracle table, any help is really appreciated?

Comment: You are missing an end quote at the end of that second line: `pwd = "<password>)`. Is that a typo from copying and pasting onto the site or is it in your code?

Comment: yes, it is the copy paste problem. that's not it.

Comment: Is `T` a valid synonym for `TRUE` in the `append` argument? (I have no idea... just looks a bit odd)

Comment: @Alex Poole, when I take out the append option, I get VMSTAT table already exists error.

Comment: I wasn't querying whether `append` was OK, it was whether it should be `append=TRUE` rather then `append=T` (as the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf) suggests, maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. My DATE field on oracle table is as DATE but on the data frame was a character. I had to use:

```
dat$DATE<-as.POSIXct(dat$DATE, format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

and it worked.